# Postman Newman how to configure "options" using when using node.js

Tags: node.js, rest, testing, postman, newman

I've created a simple newman reast api test call, I would also like to use some options for my calls.

```
const newman = require('newman');
console.log("hello");

newman.run({
    collection: 'https://www.getpostman.com/collections/4a6098a183ea90b7d8d7',
    reporters: ['cli', 'html'],
    options:'-k' //<--- *** This does not work ***
}, process.exit);
```

I'm my case the option I'm using is -k (Disables SSL verification checks and allows self-signed SSL certificates.), my my question is in general how to configure options when using newman in node.js?

Answer (score 1):

postman newman api reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#api-reference

```
newman.run({
    collection: 'https://www.getpostman.com/collections/4a6098a183ea90b7d8d7',
    reporters: ['cli', 'html'],
    insecure:'true' //<--- will set option -k
}, process.exit);
```